# why does the code show an Error in a Dafny version 4, in function fact?

Tags: dafny

```
method isPrime(n: int) returns (result: bool)
  decreases n
{
  if n < 2 {
    result := false;
  } else {
    result := true;
    var i := 2;
    while i * i <= n
      invariant 2 <= i <= n+1 && result == true
    {
      if n % i == 0 {
        result := false;
      }
      i := i + 1;
    }
  }
}

function fact(x: int) : int
  requires x >= 1;
{
  if x == 1 then 1 else x * fact(x-1)
}
```

there is an error in "function fact(x: int) : int" said: "expected rbrace" .. it's keeping show up everywhere .. what is the problem?

its result an error.

Comment: Please reload VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

For me (using Dafny 4.0), this version of the code compiles without problem:

```dafny
method isPrime(n: int) returns (result: bool)
  decreases n
{
  if n < 2 {
    result := false;
  } else {
    result := true;
    var i := 2;
    while i * i <= n
    invariant 2 <= i <= n+1 //&& result == true
    {
      if n % i == 0 {
        result := false;
      }
      i := i + 1;
    }
  }
}

function fact(x: int) : int
  requires x >= 1;
{
  if x == 1 then 1 else x * fact(x-1)
}
```

I had to comment out part of the invariant, as this does not hold for all iterations of the loop.